# How to define function for multiple urls in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I want my Codeigniter to call a function export(...) when

```
domain.com/foo/bar/show/122.export
```

also the same function if

```
domain.com/boo/for/show_all/172.export
domain.com/goo/par/detail/122.export
```

so I thought I could define that function export(...) only once
and pass the HTML code of the respective page to the export function, 
or at least the source of the call.

How can I define this for my whole CI-page?

Comment: Try using routes http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use CI's URI route

something like this should work (say your export function is in exports controller)

```
$route['([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)\.(export)'] = "exports/export/$1/$2/$3/$4";
```

So your export method will have source information.

Comment: This seams like an even better way than I had planned in the first place.